# Change style depending on browser userAgent

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I feel like I'm really close to this being correct, but it doesn't seem to be working.
Could someone please help me?

```js
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (userAgent.indexOf('OPR') != -1) {
  if (userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1) {
    //browser is chrome
    $("#evs").addClass(".chrome");
  } else {
    //browser is opera, add css
    $("#evs").addClass(".opera");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the bit, its supposed to be .toLowerCase

Comment: Okay I'll try to better explain what I'm trying to do: This code is attempting to select an object via is ID, and add a Class to is, based on the browser it's being viewed in. OPR is agent for Opera Browser, and #evs is the ID of the image in which I'm trying to move.

Comment: yea but can't I select the browser via the name, or userAgent? It still comes up as Opera version 73

Comment: So the issue I'm still having though, is that the image in question, isn't showing in Opera or Chrome now, when I add this code. And I can't figure out why...

Comment: It seems that the class isn't being added to the image, with this code. `<img id="evs" class="" src="sources/housekeeping/evs_dark.png" height="247" width="554px">`

Comment: have you included the jQuery library? Or you need pure vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I didn't have jQuery active on the page I'm working on, so I added it, but it still isn't showing.

Comment: Am I setting the styling correctly? `.dark-mode #evs .opera{
 position: absolute;
 right: 460px;
 bottom: -259px;
 visibility: visible !important;
}`

Comment: Found your other issue. See my answer below.

Comment: Other than some positioning issues now, this seems to be working! Thank you!!!

Comment: I got it all sorted, this works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you use `.toLowercase()` but you're trying to match uppercase chars: `'OPR'` , `'Chrome'`
- jQuery's .addClass() expects a className string (**without the dot**) like: `$("#evs").addClass("chrome");` - same goes for JS's classList.add() method:

Here's my suggestion:

```js
const UA = navigator.userAgent;
const EL_evs = document.querySelector("#evs");

if (/Chrome\//i.test(UA)) {       // Case insensitive (i) if needed?

  if (/OPR\//.test(UA)) {         // Case sensitive
    EL_evs.classList.add("UA-opera");
  } else if (/Edg\//.test(UA)) {  // Case sensitive
    EL_evs.classList.add("UA-edge");
  } else {
    EL_evs.classList.add("UA-chrome");
  }

}
```

```css
.UA-chrome { background: gold; }
.UA-edge   { background: blue; }
.UA-opera  { background: red; }
```

```html
<div id="evs">TEST</div>
```